# Python (pyscripter)

Tags: python, pyscripter

Following Code is not terminating not sure why.

```
def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
import random # imports random

def GuessingGame (): # creating def function for GuessingGame
    yes = ['y', 'Y', 'Yes', 'yes'] # setting variables
    rng = random.Random ()
    numbertoguess = rng.randrange (1,10)  # setting random number between 1 and 10
    correctguesses = 0
    winpercent = 0
    attempts = 0
    name = input('What is your name? ') # asks user for name and introduces the game
    print('Nice to meet you', name, '! I am going to pick a random number and you will have 3 tries to guess it.'
    'Good luck!')

while attempts < 3: # creates a function
    guess = int(input('Guess the number I have chosen between 1 and 10. '))
    attempts += 1
    if guess == numbertoguess: # tells user if guess is right
        print('Great guess, youre right', name, '!')
        correctguesses += 1 # adds on to correct guesses
        winpercent = float((correctguesses*100)/attempts)# determines percent of correct answers
        print ('You have' , correctguesses, 'correct guesses!')
        print ('You are right', winpercent, 'of the time.')
    elif guess > numbertoguess: # tells if guess is too high
        print('The number is lower than', guess, "!")
    elif guess < numbertoguess: # tells if guess is too low
        print('The number is higher than', guess, "!")
    else: # tells when you have lost
        print('Wrong, the number was', numbertoguess, '!')
        print ('You have' , correctguesses, 'correct guesses!')
        print ('You are right', winpercent, 'of the time.')
gameover = input("Do you want to play again? Yes or No? ")

while gameover is 'Yes' or 'yes': GuessingGame () #oportunity to  play again
else: exit() # ends games
print ('The program will now terminate. Goodbye.')
GuessingGame () # calls game
```

Comment: You shouldn't have any code at top level. Instead insert all the top-level code into `main` and then put the `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` as the *last* two lines of the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
import random # imports random
# Your 2 while loops were not indented causing them not to know what the attempt variable, made in the GuessingGame function was.
def GuessingGame (): # creating def function for GuessingGame
    yes = ['y', 'Y', 'Yes', 'yes'] # setting variables
    rng = random.Random ()
    numbertoguess = rng.randrange (1,10)  # setting random number between 1 and 10
    correctguesses = 0
    winpercent = 0
    attempts = 0
    name =  raw_input('What is your name? ') # asks user for name and introduces the game (inputs used in strings must be raw.) 
    print('Nice to meet you', name ,'! I am going to pick a random number and you will have 3 tries to guess it.'
'Good luck!')

    while attempts < 3: # creates a function
        guess = int(input('Guess the number I have chosen between 1 and 10. '))
        attempts += 1
        if guess == numbertoguess: # tells user if guess is right
            print('Great guess, youre right', name, '!')
            correctguesses += 1 # adds on to correct guesses
            winpercent = float((correctguesses*100)/attempts)# determines percent of correct answers
            print ('You have' , correctguesses, 'correct guesses!')
            print ('You are right', winpercent, 'of the time.')
        elif guess > numbertoguess: # tells if guess is too high
            print('The number is lower than', guess, "!")
        elif guess < numbertoguess: # tells if guess is too low
            print('The number is higher than', guess, "!")
        else: # tells when you have lost
            print('Wrong, the number was', numbertoguess, '!')
            print ('You have' , correctguesses, 'correct guesses!')
            print ('You are right', winpercent, 'of the time.')
    gameover = raw_input("Do you want to play again? Yes or No? ")

while gameover is 'Yes' or 'yes': GuessingGame () #oportunity to  play again
    else: exit() # ends games
    print ('The program will now terminate. Goodbye.')
GuessingGame () # calls game`enter code here`
```

There are 2 reasons that your code did not work. The first one is that the while loops were not inside the GuessingGame function, causing them not to know what the variables made there were. The second reason is that if you're going to use a input in a string, you must use raw_input(), not plain input(). I hope this helped!

Comment: When i try running my program it tells me "global name raw_input is not defined". I am running python 3.3.5 with pyscripter if that means anything.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your problem is in the line `while gameover is 'Yes' or 'yes': GuessingGame ()` If the user enters yes to if they want to play the game again, you are calling the function over and over again, which is known as recursion. If I'm correct, this will reset attempts to 0, thus never exiting your while loop. I am not sure if this is what you want, but instead of calling GuessingGame(), writing `while gameover is 'Yes' or 'yes': continue` will actually go back to the top of the while loop.

Also, I'm not quite sure of what the importance of defining a main() function is, when the body of the function is just pass. Instead, you should write your GuessinGame() above if **name** == '**main**', and then have your `while` loop below if **name** == '**main**'

Comment: I'm to python and i'm not quite sure what you are saying in the second paragraph.

Comment: @Cookebooks I personally like to write functions above  if __name__ == '__main__' and call them under  if __name__ == '__main__'. This lets other people know what I'm trying to call and whatnot. And I was trying to ask about the importance of `main()`, as its body is just pass. If you weren't aware, you do not have to define a `main()` every time you want to execute a python program